# Where to store a DataSource resource in a Java web app?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, servlets, jdbc

This is a rookie question. What's the best place to put

```
@Resource
private DataSource ds;
```

in a web application? Do I put it in a servlet, context listener or maybe there's a better place for it?
Also, do I create a new Connection object in my doGet()/doPost() or should I do it somewhere else?
What's the best practice for stuff like this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the best place to put `@Resource DataSource` in a web application? Do I put it in a servlet, context listener or maybe there's a better place for it?

In the very same class where you'd like to call `DataSource#getConnection()`.

> Also, do I create a new Connection object in my doGet()/doPost() or should I do it somewhere else?

You usually do that in a method of a DAO class where you'd like to interact with the DB, in a `try` block where you close the `Connection` (and `Statement` and `ResultSet`, if any) in the `finally` block.

In a more abstracted and flexible setup, you could also do `DataSource#getConnection()` in a DAO manager class or a transaction manager class.